# Core data : Clear data which is added with PersistentStoreWithType:NSInMemoryStoreType

Tags: ios, core-data, persistent-storage

I am using core data for the first time in one of my application. There is a requirement like for particular scenario I do not want to save data in data base. For this I read the apple doc and come up with PersistentStoreWithType:NSInMemoryStoreType. And it works well and those object resides in memory till we kill it.

But now I am facing some issues in it. I want to clear that data at some point and I want to download it again so how can I clear all the data from store which are added for persistent store of type "NSInMemoryStoreType"?

Is there any way I can remove it from memory without killing application?

Comment: You could try to remove the in-memory-store from the persistent store coordinate and add a new one. Perhaps reset the managed object context first.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete all objects.

```
for (NSManagedObject *object in fetchedObjects) {
   [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:object];
}
```

Or if you have never "saved":

```
[self.managedObjectContext rollback];
```

Comment: Yes I can delete objects with above method. But I want to delete specific objects. I have used NSInMemoryStoreType as well as NSSQLiteStoreType types. And I want to delete only NSInMemoryStoreType objects.

Comment: Presumably you have set the store type via model configurations. Through the model you can get at the configuration and iterate through the entities with `entitiesForConfiguration`.

Comment: You have typo: in first code example, it is: [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:object];